# How to use append correctly without causing HTML Table distortion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, append

I have a table which has links rows loaded dynamically from a MySQL database.

Currently to provide users quick access to the start of each new letter as in using named anchors, I have the following script which is working just fine in dynamically creating anchors and a small sample of the HTML table.  You can see from the code that the script keeps adding it to the front of the TD tag which is causing the table to be distorted.  New to JavaScript and not sure where I am going wrong.  I found the script online.

All in all I would like the Named Anchor to show at the inside the TD tag in front of all content.

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
char = "";
$('.myTable').each(function(){
    td = $(this);
    $(this).child('td#front').each(function(){
        x = $(this).text()[0];
        if(x!=char){
            char = x;
            q = $('<div class="lettergroup" />').appendTo(td);
            $('<a name="'+char+'" />').appendTo(q);
            $('<h2>'+char+'</h2>').appendTo(q);
        }
        $(this).appendTo(q);
    });
});

$('.lettergroup').each(function(lgi){
    lg = $(this);
    c = $(this).child('td#front');
    l = c.length;
    h = Math.ceil(l/2);
    if(l>1){
        lc = $('<div class="lettercolumn" />').prepend(lg);
        c.each(function(si){
            if(si==h) lc = $('<div class="lettercolumn" />').appendTo(lg);
            $(this).prepend(lc);
                
        });
    $('<br class="clear" />').appendTo(lg);
    }
});




});//]]>  

</script>
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <a class="letterAnchor" name="A"></a><td class="front">A Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: oh damn, there are a lot of wrong things

Comment: Well all I really need to figure out right now is how to make the anchor show up inside the TD tag and not before it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option I was needing was prependTo.

prepend by itself without To does not handle HTML

See this page for more details.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_html.asp